# tvOS AVPlayerViewController Video Info

Tags: tvos, avplayerviewcontroller

In the built-in apps for tvOS when you watch a video it shows information about that video when you swipe down. I can't find any information on how a developer can do this same thing. I'm sure it is designed to be possible as it says "Swipe down for info" Has anybody figured this out? I'm using AVPlayerViewController.

Comment: If you check the logs, when the "info" view is appearing after you swipe down, a warning appears : Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged <AVNowPlayingPlaybackControlsViewController: 0x126140c00>. So it seems that they are using a detached view controller !

Comment: I can't get the "Info" section to appear of that "swipe down" pane to appear. It only shows the "Audio" section. For each of my `AVPlayerItem`s I'm appending `AVMutableMetadataItem`s to the `externalMetadata` array but it still doesn't show up. Apple says it's possible here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerViewController_Class/ under "External Metadata". See also https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVPlayerItem/externalMetadata

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To get the "Info" section to show up in the "Swipe down for info" pane in [`AVPlayerViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerViewController_Class/) you create [`AVMutableMetadataItem`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMutableMetadataItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/c:objc(cs)AVMutableMetadataItem)s with the `AVMetadataKeySpaceCommon` keyspace and any of the following keys:

```
AVMetadataCommonKeyTitle
AVMetadataCommonKeyDescription
AVMetadataiTunesMetadataKeyContentRating
AVMetadataQuickTimeMetadataKeyGenre
```

and add them to the `AVPlayerItem`'s [`externalMetadata`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVPlayerItem/externalMetadata) array. In order for each `AVMutableMetadataItem` to show up you must at least set the `identifier`, `extendedLanguageTag`, and `value` properties. Here's an example:

```
let mediaItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: mediaURL)

let titleMetadataItem = AVMutableMetadataItem()
titleMetadataItem.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
titleMetadataItem.key = AVMetadataCommonKeyTitle
titleMetadataItem.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpaceCommon
titleMetadataItem.value = "The Title"
                        
let descriptionMetadataItem = AVMutableMetadataItem()
descriptionMetadataItem.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
descriptionMetadataItem.key = AVMetadataCommonKeyDescription
descriptionMetadataItem.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpaceCommon
descriptionMetadataItem.value = "This is the description"

mediaItem.externalMetadata.append(titleMetadataItem)
mediaItem.externalMetadata.append(descriptionMetadataItem)
```

This isn't well-documented. [This forum post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/62104#62104) was critical to figuring this out.

---

Objective-C example:

```
AVPlayerItem *mediaItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:mediaURL];

AVMutableMetadataItem *titleMetadataItem = [[AVMutableMetadataItem alloc] init];
titleMetadataItem.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale;
titleMetadataItem.key = AVMetadataCommonKeyTitle;  
titleMetadataItem.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpaceCommon;  
titleMetadataItem.value = @"The Title";

NSArray *externalMetadata = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:titleMetadataItem, nil];

mediaItem.externalMetadata = externalMetadata;
```

Comment: I am having an issue where the "info"/metadata fades out after it loads on the "Swipe down for info" view.  Any idea what would do that?

Comment: @SerenadeX, I believe it's a bug with the Simulator. I see the same thing. However, testing on an actual device, I don't have that problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94974/discussion-between-jenel-ejercito-myers-and-jeff-bowen).

Comment: I'm getting this compilation error: "Property 'externalMetadata' not found on object of type 'AVPlayerItem *' - Using tvOS 9.1 with the very latest XCode 7.2. Any ideas?

Comment: @LuisArtola, are you certain your target is tvOS? I saw this error when I first tried to access `externalMetadata` in my iOS target.

Comment: @JeffBowen yeap, it's tvos, it's running on an actual Apple TV. I got it to compile but not to work completely. I discovered that just by importing modules does not automatically link the right frameworks. I had to do @@import AVKit AND still add AVKit frawework in project settings. Now it compiles and runs. But, when I swipe down on the remote my custom title and description do not show up.

Comment: What is the purpose of AVMetadataQuickTimeMetadataKeyGenre?

Answer (score 6):

If you need to have more options in player menu, it is better to create a `UIViewController` with custom information and settings option [based on your requirement] and set it as `AVPlayerViewController`'s `customInfoViewController`.

**This is available from tvOS 11.0+**

[image]

Official apple docs on this: [Apple Docs Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller/2868498-custominfoviewcontroller?language=objc)

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Jeff's answer, this is the function I use to avoid repetition:

```
private func setupMetadata(data: String, key: (NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol))->AVMutableMetadataItem{
    
    let metadataItem = AVMutableMetadataItem()
    metadataItem.locale = NSLocale.current
    metadataItem.key = key
    metadataItem.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpaceCommon
    metadataItem.value = data as (NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)?
    
    return metadataItem
    
}
```

and in use:

```
    //in AVPlayerViewControler
    //Suppose you have an already initialized avPlayerItem
    avPlayerItem.externalMetadata.append(self.setupMetadata(data: "title of video", key: AVMetadataCommonKeyTitle as (NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)))
    avPlayerItem.externalMetadata.append(self.setupMetadata(data: "RugDealer", key: AVMetadataCommonKeyAuthor as (NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)))
    avPlayerItem.externalMetadata.append(self.setupMetadata(data: "Description of the video", key: AVMetadataCommonKeyDescription as (NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)))
```

Comment: @Fattie Your bounty -- do you have a specific question, or did you actually want to "reward an existing answer"?

Comment: hi @Krokomot I don't really understand your question or why you're asking it?  The blue box at the top of the screen will give you complete information on bounties.  If you have any general questions about the nature of bounties, maybe use the meta site or ask an admin, IDK?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the above answers, I also wanted to add artwork, genres and content rating to the top shelf. This being slightly different from whats mentioned. They can be added as follows to the externalMetadata array.

```
//Sets the content rating on the top shelf
AVMutableMetadataItem *ratingInfo = [[AVMutableMetadataItem alloc] init];
ratingInfo.key = AVMetadataiTunesMetadataKeyContentRating;
ratingInfo.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpaceiTunes;
ratingInfo.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
ratingInfo.value = @"PG-13"; //Rating of the video
ratingInfo.extendedLanguageTag = @"und";
[externalMetadata addObject:ratingInfo];

//Sets the thumbnail on the shelf
AVMutableMetadataItem *artwork1 = [[AVMutableMetadataItem alloc] init];
artwork1.key = AVMetadataCommonKeyArtwork;
artwork1.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpaceCommon;
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:artworkAddress]];
artwork1.value = imageData;
artwork1.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
[externalMetadata addObject:artwork1];

//Sets the Genre on the shelf
AVMutableMetadataItem *genresInfo = [[AVMutableMetadataItem alloc] init];
genresInfo.key = AVMetadataQuickTimeMetadataKeyGenre;
genresInfo.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpaceQuickTimeMetadata;
genresInfo.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
genresInfo.value = @"Drama, Medical";
[externalMetadata addObject:genresInfo];
```

Comment: Careful using dataWithContentsOfURL since that's a synchronous call

Comment: Thanks @BrianFLeighty, hadn't taken that into consideration. This can cause issues with high quality images. But most likely these artwork are smaller in size. Thanks though.

Answer (score 3):

#### @kemicofaghost answer updated

Here's the fantastic answer of @kemicofaghost updated

```
 func meta(_ data: String, key: AVMetadataKey) -> AVMutableMetadataItem {

    let mdi = AVMutableMetadataItem()
    mdi.locale = NSLocale.current
    mdi.key = key as (NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)
    mdi.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpace.common
    mdi.value = data as (NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)?
    return mdi
 }
```

and then

```
 someItem.externalMetadata.append(meta("Episode 13", key:.commonKeyTitle) )
```

(It will conveniently auto-complete the many keys for you. They are listed here.)

Note too that Apple finally have a page **explaining some of the many values** ...

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/customizing_the_tvos_playback_experience

Answer (score 1):

FYI, I couldn't get this to show up on a simulator running tvOS 12.2 or 13 (beta). What finally got it working was adding `metadataItem.locale = NSLocale.current`. Comment that out, it doesn't appear.